# SAS proc rank is omitting a rank i.e. is generating 9 ranks when it is supposed to be generating 10

Tags: sas

```
proc rank data=___ out=____ ties=low
    groups=10; 
    var variable_name1;
    ranks variable_name2;
run;
```

This code is generating ranks (variable_name2) from 0-9 with only 7 missing. Anyone know why that's the case?

variable_name1 is distributed as follows:

- mean = 440
- stddev 12
- min = 217
- max = 474

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have too many ties, repeat of a single value. This means that your 7/8 or 6/7th ranks are essentially the same.

Run a proc freq on your data and you'll find that you have a single number that accounts for more than 10% of your data.